# Two Questions, How to Count Lines in jQuery/javascript and/or How to Get text that's Hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, documentation, wysiwyg

I'm trying to create a WYSIWYG editor that's custom and spans multiple divs if the div height is matched. Does anyone know a way to do this?

I was thinking you could count the lines first and that's by knowing the line-height. If that's the case, what's a good method to grab the text of a div that makes it over 200px and push it to a new div?

How do I iterate through lines of text in a div that ONLY has the natural breaks?

Another method is to max the height out on a div and set overflow to hidden. But then how do I natural get the text that is hidden from a div?

If anyone knows of an answer or solution, we would greatly appreciate it :P  Thanks. If there is even a WYSIWYG editor out there that is as good as Google Docs, also let us know!

Much appreciated. Love StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

How about using [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). Its really good and you can customize and reduce the size suitable to your needs.

Comment: can I max out the height for the text area and have text move to another textarea if it exceeds the height?

Comment: Could you explain a little more...tinymce has lots of hooks which u can use...it's just a textarea that is marked as rte in tinymce..so you can do all the normal stuff with CSS n JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Read about word wrapping / text wrapping

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap

Comment: Nothing about the relationships for Javascript and Jquery, detecting number of lines and seeing what text is overflowed

Example: <div style="overflow:hidden">dsfsdf dsafjskadlfj ####</div>

Pretend '####' was overflowed and not shown on a webpage, can jquery detect that?